# How to interpret some fixed phrase/idiom when there is another literal meaning?

Tags: idioms, interpretation

I come across this question when I encounter the phrase "for the record".

According to [the Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/record?q=for%20the%20record),

> **for the record**
>
> Meaning: something that you say before you tell someone something important that you want them to remember
>
> Example: *And, just for the record, we were never any more than good friends.*

So this is the idiomatic or fixed meaning of this phrase. But what if I just mean to record (i.e. store) a piece of information. For example,

> I have included the date of travel in the claim form for the record.

Is it good or common to do so? Or I have to stay away from using idioms/fixed phrase as other meanings.

Comment: They don't really have different meanings, other than one has a physical record and the other does not (think of it as a mental record regarding *remember*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example is flawed because you're using the word *record* incorrectly. If you wanted to use *record* to mean storing a piece of information, your example sentence would be something like:

> I have **recorded** the date of travel in the claim form.

You would never get a collision between the idiom and your sentence because in *for the record*, record is a noun, whereas in your example it should a verb and thus can't be used the same way.

If you wanted to refer to a physical record, the sentence would likely take a different form there too, something closer to:

> I have included the date of travel in the claim form **in** the record.

---

With regards to your question regarding whether you should stay away from idioms and fixed phrases in sentences, **it depends**. If you establish enough context, it shouldn't matter. Let's take a phrase like *on the ball*.

> He's on the ball.

Without context, I would assume the meaning of *on the ball* to be its idiomatic one. However, if you establish some context, you can make it a lot more clear.

> I saw it bouncing before he fell. He's on the ball.
>
> He got all his work in early. He's on the ball.

In both cases, the added context makes it a lot more clear which meaning is implied.

The more generic your idiom or phrase is the less worried I would be about it. If you're ever in doubt about the clarity of your message, don't use an idiomatic phrase. Plenty of ways to skin a cat, so to speak.

Comment: To whoever has an issue with this answer, could you let me know what you disagree with? I would be more than happy to address it.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases, context (and common sense) will make it clear that a literal meaning is intended. For example, if someone, handing you a straw, says "this is the last straw" when you are in a restaurant and asking for a straw.

However, in your example it is not clear that you intended anything other than the idiom: it is ambiguous.

The solution is simple. Idioms are a subset of fixed expressions that rely heavily on certain phrasing. It is easy to "break" an idiom so that the only interpretation is literal:

- Change a word (or two). Depending on the details, your example may be able to be reworded as:
  *I have included the date of travel in the claim form **in** the record.*
  *I have included the date of travel in the claim form for **my** record.*
- Add a word. Specifically, add either *actual* or *literal* (or their adverb derivatives):
  *I have included the date of travel in the claim form for the **actual** record.*
  Another example: *He fell off the **literal** wagon.*